# TypeScript: Declare a global variable with the type from other ambient external module without import

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

I have this code in a global.d.ts file, to make a global shortcuts to certain functions:

```
///<reference path="../../typings/react/react.d.ts"/>
declare var a: React.HTMLFactory;
```

But the compiler fails with a name 'React' not found. If I add:

```
import React = require('react');
```

it finds the type, but then the declaration is modulized, which is not what I want.

Is it possible to declare such a global using TypeScript 1.4? Or maybe 1.5?

Comment: Where is the code of `react.d.ts`? There is no exported member `HTMLFactory` in the file [from DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts).

Comment: @Tarh I do use the DefinitelyTyped declaration... but there are no exports in that file what so ever? How does that even work?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the definition file before to post my comment. There is just a definition for an external module `"react"`. The namespace `React` no longer exists... I'm going to write an answer, I need more formatting.

Comment: @Tarh I'm looking forward to it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `React` as a namespace (internal module)

The file [react-global.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react-global.d.ts) contains a definition of an internal module `React`:

```
// -------- global.d.ts --------
///<reference path="react-global.d.ts"/>
declare var a: React.HTMLFactory;
```

## `React` as an external module

The file [react.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts) contains a definition of an external module `"react"`.

First, I suggest to use TypeScript 1.5-alpha because the syntax of modules is modified in aligning TS on ES6. External modules from ES6 are the future.

To use the external module:

```
// -------- global.d.ts --------
///<reference path="react.d.ts"/>
import * as React from 'react'; // syntax ES6 / TS 1.5
declare var a: React.HTMLFactory;
// export something here
```

NB. The `///<reference` is optional here because the file `.d.ts` has the same name than the external module.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out right away. To be sure, you are saying it is not possible in in 1.4 to reference/redeclare an external module as a namespace?

Comment: One thing I still don't understand, though, is why the TS documentation for ambient external module uses exports, but there are none in react.ts.d. Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: I edited. I tried to compile some code and I'm not sure this is a valid solution.

Comment: I kind of got the internal module version working by copying the entire external module code into a namespace. That leaves me with both the external and the internal implementation. I'm not sure, I understand your edit though... could you elaborate on that? I have unfortunately not been able to compile using the 1.5-alpha yet. I'm still working on it :)

Comment: I wish I could do something like `declare module React = "react"`

Comment: I've upvoted the answer, but am still looking for a solution, if any :)

Comment: I found the solution: there are two definition files for React: `react.d.ts` and `react-global.d.ts`. Just use the second.

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is: ts compiler could not compose internal (with includes - `///<reference>` instruction) and external (`AMD` or `commonjs`) modules. So you could not use `///<reference>` tags with `require` function.

Do you compile that file with AMD flag?

Comment: It's compiled with the commonjs flag... I'm not exactly sure what you mean "include tags"?

Comment: ///<reference> works as a include. See result file. But it is incompartible with external modules (comonjs is external module).

Comment: I'm sorry Pavel, I really hope this will not sound too rude, but I do not understand the answer. Is it a solution to the problem, or just an explanation of why it does not work?

Comment: I am sorry too. Try to describe possible problem.
1. When you use ts compiler without `--module` flag, it replaces `///<reference>` tags replacing it with file content (like include in C++, like preprocessor work). 2. When you use ts compiler with `--module` flag, it ignores any `///<reference>` tag. It is because internal and external modules is incompatible.

Comment: `///<reference>` is not incompatible with external modules. See [at the end of this post](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242#issuecomment-83694181).

Comment: Ah... thank you, I think I understand you now. But even though I compile with any module flag at all, it still won't find the type. And even if I copy the entire content of the referenced module into the global.ts.d file, it can't find the type React.HTMLFactory.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you last post before I posted. I'll check it out right away :)